# Displaying records that have more than 5 days inbetween them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, datediff

I have 2 tables,

**tblCustomer**

> CustomerID(PK), FirstName, Surname)

**tblPurchases**

> PurchaseID(PK), PurchaseDate, Qty, CustomerID(FK).

I want to display all the customers who purchased products after five (5) days or more since their last purchase in the following manner.

```
FirstName      diff in days since last purchase
Alex           7
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below query.

```
SELECT FirstName, DATEDIFF(DAY, t.PurchaseDate, getdate()) as 'diff in days since last purchase'
FROM tblCustomer c
 JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, MAX(PurchaseDate)PurchaseDate
       FROM tblPurchases
       GROUP BY CustomerID )t ON c.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, PurchaseDate, getdate())>5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName, 
DATEDIFF(DAY, t.PurchaseDate, getdate())  'diff in days since last purchase'
FROM tblCustomer c
 JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, MAX(PurchaseDate)PurchaseDate
       FROM tblPurchases
       GROUP BY CustomerID )t ON c.CustomerID=t.CustomerID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, t.PurchaseDate, getdate())>5
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number based on the last purchase date for each `CustomerId` by joining both the tables.

Then find the difference in number of days between [`current date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188383.aspx) and `PurchaseDate` by using [**`DATEDIFF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx).
And also give the number of days difference in the `WHERE` clause.

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY t.[CustomerID]
        ORDER BY t.[PurchaseDate] DESC
    ), t.[CustomerID], t.[FirstName], t.[PurchaseDate]
    FROM (
       SELECT t1.[CustomerID], t1.[FirstName], t2.[PurchaseDate]
       FROM [tblCustomer] t1
       JOIN [tblPurchases] t2
       ON t1.[CustomerID] = t2.[CustomerID]
    )t
)
SELECT [FirstName], 
DATEDIFF(DAY, [PurchaseDate], GETDATE()) AS [diff in days since last purchase]
FROM CTE
WHERE [rn] = 1
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, [PurchaseDate], GETDATE()) > 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, [PurchaseDate], GETDATE()) AS DiffInDays
    FROM @tblPurchases
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, [PurchaseDate], GETDATE()) > 5
)   
SELECT
    C.FirstName,    
    MAX(DiffInDays) AS DiffInDays
FROM T
LEFT JOIN @tblCustomer C ON T.CustomerId=C.CustomerId
GROUP BY C.FirstName
```